# Loading Firebase remote config in Angular 8 project

Tags: angular, firebase

Since Firebase has released remote config to the web, I'm trying to make use of it to make my life easier over the holiday break. I have a webapp that a client is using for their company website, and I want to set a remote config property that will load their holiday hours.

HTML template

```
<div *ngIf="holidays" class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Holiday Hours</h5>
      <p class="card-text">
          Holiday hours go here
      </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Typescript snippit

```
  holidays = boolean;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    const remoteConfig = firebase.remoteConfig();

    remoteConfig.fetchTimeMillis = 360000;

    remoteConfig.defaultConfig = ({
      'holidays': false,
    })

    remoteConfig.fetchAndActivate()
    .then(() => {
    this.holidays = remoteConfig.getBoolean('holidays')
    console.log(this.holidays);
    })

  }

}
```

Deployed code into Firebase reports 'remoteConfig is not a function'

Angular refused to build until I declared the holiday variable outside of ngOnInit

Comment: According to your `package.json`, what's the version of `firebase` you're using?

Comment: "firebase": "^7.3.0"

Comment: This blog could be helpful: https://arunraj6.medium.com/angular13-with-firebase-remote-config-483438f4efa1

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're using [@angular/fire](https://github.com/angular/angularfire) and an outdated version of `fireabse` (below 7).

What you may want to do, is to wait for [this pull request](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/pull/2187) to be merged to the main branch, or install (you may see PEER DEPENDENCY warning since @angular/fire doesn't support firebase 7 yet) by running:

```
npm install firebase@7.3.0
```

or higher.

Comment: No, I'm deliberately not using @angluar/fire because it doesn't yet support remote config. I'm using the official firebase library: "firebase": "^7.3.0"

Comment: Well, it looks like they support it since 30 minutes ago - https://github.com/angular/angularfire/releases/tag/5.3.0-rc.0